# Performance Issues with loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, cplex, opl

I'm having huge performance problems with my JavaScript code. 
I try to pre-process data for a Cplex-Model in OPL, the code is written in JavaScript.

I already tried to speed it up by adding the first if-clause (`if A[1][3]=""`, `A[1][k] =""` for every `k` > 3) , but it still takes my computer more than 2 hours to process just this code...

```
Jnr = 1000,
Mnr = 35;
```

```
while (j <= Jnr) {
  while (i <= Mnr) {
    while (k <= Mnr) {
      if (A[j][k] == "") {
        break;
      } else if (A[j][k] == I[i].name) {
        counter[j][i] = counter[j][i] + 1;
      }
      k = k + 1;
    }
    k = 1;
    i = i + 1;
  }
  i = 1;
  j = j + 1;
}
j = 1;
```

Is there anyway to speed up the process?

I appreciate your help

Comment: What is your desired return value? This is slow because it's a triply nested loop. ~1.2 million iterations

Comment: An array that returns the amount of times the string I[i].names is in A[j][.....]

Comment: Please including a sample of your A array

Comment: This is probably more of an algorithm design and optimization problem, than a Javascript question. Have you tried coding this in another language? If so, does it run vastly faster?

Comment: An exampe could be: 
[ "AAAA" , "BBBB", "ABCD", "","","","","","",...""]

Comment: I would expect that some combination of `map` and `reduce` would help here, but without knowing what's in `A` and `I`, and what the end result is supposed to be, it's hard to say exactly what.

Comment: Arash No I haven't, because I have to pre process data for a Cplex modell (you have to write it in JS) and I tried to avoid to importing it from an external class...

Comment: So the content of A are letters that stand for machines, 
I is the set of machines. 
I need to find out, how often a Job has to be proccessed on a specific machine

for example for 
A= "Machine1", "Machine4", "Machine5", "Machine1"
B = "Machine1","Machine", Machine 3 ... "Machine 5"

counter has to be= [2,0,0,1,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very good idea to use scripting for big loops. If you write that directly in OPL this will be much faster:

```
int Jnr = 1000;
int Mnr = 35;

tuple t
{
string name;
}

t I[i in 1..Mnr]=<"A">;

string A[i in 1..Jnr][j in 1..Mnr]=((i+j)%2==0)?"A":"B";
int counter[1..Jnr][1..Mnr];

execute
{
var i=1;
var j=1;
var k=1;

while (j <= Jnr) {
  while (i <= Mnr) {
    while (k <= Mnr) {
      if (A[j][k] == "") {
        break;
      } else if (A[j][k] == I[i].name) {
        counter[j][i] = counter[j][i] + 1;
      }
      k = k + 1;
    }
    k = 1;
    i = i + 1;
  }
  i = 1;
  j = j + 1;
}
j = 1;
}


int counter2[i in 1..Jnr][j in 1..Mnr]=sum(k in 1..Mnr) (I[k].name==A[i][k]);

execute
{
counter2;
}


assert forall(i in 1..Jnr,j in 1..Mnr) counter[i][j]==counter2[i][j];
```

counter takes 9 s on my machine, whereas counter2 takes 0.3 s

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your great answer, since I am new to OPL  I did not think about that
regards

Answer (score 0):

You could save one level of looping by first creating a map for mapping a name to an index *i*. Also, `indexOf` will probably work faster than checking for a an empty string within the inner loop:

```
// Preprocessing
const names = {};
for (let i = 1; i <= Mnr; i++) names[I[i].name] = i;

// Main
for (let j = 1; j <= Jnr; j++) {
    const row = A[j];
    const counterRow = counter[j];
    let m = row.indexOf("")-1;
    if (m < 0) m = Jnr;
    for (let k = 1; k <= m; k++) {
        let i = names[row[k]];
        if (i !== undefined) counterRow[i]++;
    }
}
```

NB: your arrays are having values starting at index 1. This is atypical for JavaScript (and many other languages). Consider populating your arrays so the first entry is at 0 and the last at `Jnr - 1`, ...etc. This might also increase a bit the performance, as the parser's optimiser may work better in that case.

Comment: Hi trincot, 
Thanks for your answer, I will try it out 
I only use javascript to preproccess date for a Cplex-Model. In Cplex it is typical to start your array at index 1. It took me a while to get used to it, too...